# Why does not <tr> tag take the full width of <tbody> tag?

Tags: html, css, sass, html-table

I have a standard Materialize table in my Vue component. I have tried to apply 100% of width to **tr**, 95% of width to **td**, and remaining 5% to a small icon. However, it seems that **tr** does not take the full width of **tbody**. Here is my HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Choices</th>
            <th>
                <button class="btn-small btn-floating waves-effect waves-light white" @click="deleteChoice(index)">
                    <i class="material-icons right red-text text-darken-3">delete_sweep</i>
                </button>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="input-choice" type="text"></td>
            <a @click="deleteChoice(index)">
                <i class="material-icons red-text text-darken-3">delete</i>
            </a>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="input-choice" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please, ignore the Vue stuff within the code.

And here is my CSS/SCSS stuff:

```
tbody {
    tr {
        border: none;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;

        td {
            padding: 0;
            width: 95%;
        }
        a{
            align-self: flex-end;
            margin-left: auto;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because it isn't `display: table-row` any more.

Comment: Your `tr` use 100% width in `tbody`, if you got problem with it check your no-scoped other components in Vue.

Comment: Can you build a fiddle, and comment out your modifications to fix the width.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, guys. As @Quentin mentioned, the problem was stemming from the display property. Since my tr was not table-row anymore, it was not able to take the full width.